# Kindly explain this graph which is related to internal combustion engines

Tags: mechanical, energy, turbomachinery

[image]

Hello,

I am not getting this graph which is related to the Internal Combustion Engine.

Comment: Is it the 3D graph and taking cross sections that you are not getting or what the variables represent?

Comment: What do you think "mechanical characteristics" are? Or "load control characteristics"?

Comment: what is y (the vertical axis of the graph)? It does not look like power, torque or efficiency for a real engine.